# Java Applet: My program creates more circle and rectangles than I want. Sometimes they are only half drawn

Tags: java, swing, random, geometry, rectangles

Design and implement an applet that draws 3 circles of random radius (a radius between 20 and 100 inclusively) and 3 rectangles of random width and height (a width between 50 and 150 inclusively and a height between 30 and 90 inclusively) in random locations. Draw a string with your name on the bottom right corner of the applet. Use a width of 400 and a height of 300 for your applet.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Applet extends JApplet
{

    public void paint(Graphics circle)
    {
        // Height and width of window
        final int MAX_WIDTH = 400;
        final int MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
        resize(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

        // Creates random diameter for each circle
        Random rand = new Random();
        int diameter1 = rand.nextInt(81) + 20;
        int diameter2 = rand.nextInt(81) + 20;
        int diameter3 = rand.nextInt(81) + 20;

        // Draws circles
        circle.drawOval(rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH), rand.nextInt(MAX_HEIGHT),
                        diameter1, diameter1);
        circle.drawOval(rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH), rand.nextInt(MAX_HEIGHT),
                        diameter2, diameter2);
        circle.drawOval(rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH), rand.nextInt(MAX_HEIGHT),
                        diameter3, diameter3);

        // Creates random heights and widths for rectangles
        int randWidth1 = rand.nextInt(101) + 50;
        int randWidth2 = rand.nextInt(101) + 50;
        int randWidth3 = rand.nextInt(101) + 50;

        int randHeight1 = rand.nextInt(61) + 30;
        int randHeight2 = rand.nextInt(61) + 30;
        int randHeight3 = rand.nextInt(61) + 30;

        // Draws rectangles
        circle.drawRect(rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH), rand.nextInt(MAX_HEIGHT),
                        randWidth1, randHeight1);
        circle.drawRect(rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH), rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH),
                        randWidth2, randHeight2);
        circle.drawRect(rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH), rand.nextInt(MAX_WIDTH),
                        randWidth3, randHeight3);


     }

}
```

[image: There is half a circle and more than 3 circles and rectangles]

Comment: Essentially, you've broken the painting process.  Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing/AWT. `Graphics` is also a shared resource, so ALL components which are painted during a give paint cycle will get the same `Graphics` context, this means that anything that was painted to it before hand still remains.  It'd also question the use of `JApplet`

Comment: Instead, I'd encourage you to start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead (calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting) and then put that panel in what ever top level container you want.  Dozens of reasons for this, but lets just say it will save your sanity in the long run.

Comment: How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: See the duplicate question, there are two complete examples

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: He decided to make it the last year he would teach applets